# PERMISSION_DENIED 403 error when triggering HTTP Cloud Function from Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying the [Using Cloud Tasks to trigger Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf) tutorial but when I try to run the created task I get an error:

```
Status code: 7 (PERMISSION_DENIED)
Reason for retrying: PERMISSION_DENIED(7): HTTP status code 403
```

I have created a new service account with the `Cloud Functions Invoker` role.
And modified my code so the tasks are created using this service account:

```js
const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.HttpMethod.POST,
      url,
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail: 'cloud-tasks-client@my-actual-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      },
```

The task is created from a cloud function.

I have also modified the target Cloud Function access control so it can be accessed by `allAuthenticatedUsers` with the role `Cloud Functions Invoker`.
I can test trigger the function using the cloud functions console without any error.

What did I miss? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I just figured it out. I deployed the function with `ingress-settings=internal-only`. Thinking that Cloud Tasks would be considered an internal service. I had to change this to the default `all`, then it worked. `internal-and-gclb` also did not work.

Comment: I had this issue pushing to a cloud run endpoint. I deploy several of the same application in a multi-layered prod-canary-etc setup and had just one's ingress set to `internal-only`. To reiterate the import of your answer for other travelers, check ingress on your services first!

Comment: Obviously it goes without saying, doing this will also expose the service to the public.

Comment: As @AlexanderTrauzzi mentioned this exposes your service to the public. Is there a solution that doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the IAM page, locate the Cloud task service agent service account: `service-<projectNumber>@gcp-sa-cloudtasks.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and grant the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` on it.

*It's not mentioned in your tutorial. I guess you didn't do it.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I just found out the real reason. So this IAM change was not necessary for me.

Comment: @guillaume this still doesn't work for me.